# Polylang Language Detection redirect with 301

Tags: php, wordpress, polylang

I am using polylang plugin for wordpress multi language site.
As per SEO guidelines, home page [www.myweb.com](http://www.myweb.com) should redirect to [www.myweb.com/en](http://www.myweb.com/en) with 301 status. Currently its redirecting with 302 status.
function home_requested() does this but we can't touch the plugin core functions.
I tried by adding filter for this function. Also tried by add filter for wp_redirect function but not working.
Is there any other way to sort this. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You probably fixed this already, however, posting for other people that are looking to solve this issue.

I solved it by editing the choose-lang.php file in the plugin

wp-content->plugins->polylang->frontend->choose-lang.php :277 or do a ctrl + f for 302 and replace that with 301.

Answer (score 2):

I tested below code working fine.

Add below code in functions.php file

```
add_filter('pll_redirect_home', 'my_pll_redirect_home' );
function my_pll_redirect_home( $redirect ) 
{
    header( 'Vary: Accept-Language' );
    wp_safe_redirect( $redirect, 301, POLYLANG );
    exit;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

i tested functions.php not work for me.

nano   /polylang/frontend/choose-lang.php   (line +265)

change 302 to 301. you done.

and it will reset itself after any polylang update

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).